# java maven project get file

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have maven project with three modules. The project structure is below:

```
- rootProject
   -module1
   -module2
   -module3
simple folder ->   -templates 
                      -templatefile.txt
```

Can I get templatefile.txt from templates folder?
I tried this but is not working:

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("templatefile.txt");
```

and

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/templates/templatefile.txt");
```

but it does not work to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question suggests that you have a parent project and three children and that you have created the `templates` directory at the same level as the child module directories. This would mean that the `templates` directory is not on the classpath for either the `rootProject` or any of the child modules.

The convention for a Maven project is that non Java resources should be located in `src/main/resources`. Anything placed in this directory will be on your project's classpath.

So, move the `templates` directory into `src/main/resources`.